# Get Top Three Records from a Table based on month field

Tags: mysql

I have a table in my mysql database whose structure is shown below

```
Name  | Price | Month
ABC   | 1000  | Jan2k20
Cde   | 100   | Mar2k20
efh   | 20000 | Jan2k20
lmn   | 200   | Feb2k20
opq   | 3000  | Mar2k20
rst   | 29999 | Feb2k20
```

what i want to do is get top two names price-wise from each given month.
my result should look like

```
Jan2k20 | Feb2k20 | Mar2k20
efh     | rst     | opq
ABC     | lmn     | Cde
```

i tried using if function mysql against each month but all in vain

```
   SELECT package_price,IF(bill_month='Jan2k20',name,'') AS Jan2k20
   FROM info ORDER BY package_price DESC LIMIT 2
```

Comment: what is your mysql version

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far? Stack Overflow is not a coding service.

Comment: Save yourself a world of pain. Normalise your schema.

Comment: Do you want to have month as columns?

Comment: @RusArtM sir no issues if i dont have month as column names

Comment: @Fahmi version 5.7

Comment: @Martin see my edited question

Comment: You will have to use `CASE` on your months and subquery the results you're looking for. That should give you a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK.
Let me introduce a strange solution :)

Creating an example. I've added some more values for `Jan2k20` to make example better:

```
CREATE TABLE info (name VARCHAR(100), Price INT, Month VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO info VALUES
("ABC", 1000, "Jan2k20"),
("ABC2", 2000, "Jan2k20"),
("ABC3", 100, "Jan2k20"),
("Cde", 100, "Mar2k20"),
("efh", 20000, "Jan2k20"),
("lmn", 200, "Feb2k20"),
("opq", 3000, "Mar2k20"),
("rst", 29999, "Feb2k20");
```

And here is a magic query :)

```
SELECT 
    month,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(val, ',', 2) names
FROM (
    SELECT 
        i1.`month`,
        GROUP_CONCAT(i1.name ORDER BY i1.price DESC) as val= i1.month) as val
    FROM info i1
    GROUP BY i1.month
) sq
ORDER BY month;
```

Which gives this result:

```
month       names
Feb2k20     rst,lmn
Jan2k20     efh,ABC2
Mar2k20     opq,Cde
```